# How to shuffle an ArrayMap on android

Tags: java, android

i'm generating a ArrayMap to play a card game and i want to shuffle  the arrayMap so i can pick sequentially without problems,there is some method that can help me out, like the .shuffle() that exist for Arraylists.

```
public ArrayMap<Integer,Carta> carte=new ArrayMap<>(dimensioneMazzo); 

for(int i=0;i<4;i++){
    for(int j=1;j<=10;j++){
        switch(i){
            case 0: 
                carte.put(cartePresenti,new Carta(j,Semi.Denari,false,false));
                break;
            case 1: 
                carte.put(cartePresenti,new Carta(j,Semi.Bastoni,false,false));
                break;
            case 2: 
                carte.put(cartePresenti,new Carta(j,Semi.Coppe,false,false));
                break;
            case 3: 
                carte.put(cartePresenti,new Carta(j,Semi.Spade,false,false));
                break;
            }

            this.cartePresenti=cartePresenti+1;
        }
    }
```

if there isn't a method how can i generate randomly the cards?

Comment: Why are you enumerating cards inside the map, you could use an array.

Comment: i prefer the arrayMap because it is simpler to work with objects

Comment: @pskink can you explain it better?

Comment: @pskink This won't work because you are creating a new object and therefore the changes aren't reflected on the map.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that `cartePresenti` starts at zero. This should work:

```
Random r = new Random();

int n = carte.size();
for (int i = n - 1; i > 0; i--) {  
    int j = r.nextInt(i + 1); 

    Carta temp = carte.get(i); 
    carte.put(i, carte.get(j));
    carte.put(j, temp);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternative solution using [`Collection.shuffle()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#shuffle-java.util.List-) :

```
//List of the indexes of the card in the old map
List<Integer> indexes = new ArrayList<Integer>();
//Map shuffled
Map<Integer, Carta> shuffledCarte = new ArrayMap<Integer, Carta>();

//Collect the indexes
For(int i = 0; i<carte.size(); i++) {
    indexes.add(i);
}

//Shuffle the indexes
indexes.shuffle();

//Create the new map, using the shuffled indexes
for(int j = 0; j<carte.size(); j++) {
    shuffledCarte.put(j, carte.get(idexes.get(j)));
}
```